# Is this closed point also open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $X$ be a scheme locally of finite type over $Spec(k)$. Consider a closed point $x\in X$ such that the local ring of $X$ at $x$ is isomorphic to $k$. Then is $x$ also open in $X$?

For example, when $X$ is affine, say $X=Spec(A)$, we let $\mathfrak{m}$ be the maximal ideal corresponding to $x$, then by assumption, the local ring $A_\mathfrak{m}$ is the base field $k$. I seem to be stuck here.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you handle this in the affine case?

Comment: Hint: consider the dimension of $\overline{x}$

Comment: Dear @KReiser, I have edited the question.

Comment: Dear @DavidLui, since $x$ is a closed point, its closure is an irreducible closed subset of $X$, so it has to have codimension zero. I don't know how to relate this to the dimension of the closure of $x$.